# Database design - Do I have redundancy here?

Tags: sql, anti-patterns

I have four tables: Companies, Products, Customers and Sales.  They are related as follows:

- One Company can have multiple Products
- One Company can have multiple Customers
- A Sale is a child of a Product and a Customer.  Each Sale record refers back to one Product and one Customer.

I am feeling uneasy about the fact that you can trace back from the Sale to the Company via two different routes.  This raises the potential for data integrity issues - what if the Products route says the ultimate parent is Company A, and the Customer route says it's Company B?

This sounds like a SQL-antipattern to me, but I could be wrong.  What can I do about it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. You say:

> One Company can have multiple
>   Customers

Does this mean that each `Customer` only shops at one `Company`?

If not, shouldn't the relationship between a `Customer` and a `Company` be defined by the `Products` they have purchased?

This would mean removing the `fk_Company` field (or equivalent) on the `Customer`.

However, if the relationship is instead the `Company` that the `Customer` *registered at*, this is different.

In that case, if there was a conflict between the `Products` bought and the `Company` the `Customer` "belongs to", it is not a real conflict - the conflict would be between the `Company` the `Customer` *registered* at, and the `Company` that the `Customer` has *just* shopped at, i.e. not a real conflict.

The ultimate question is, what is the relationship between a `Customer` and a `Company` -  is it where the `Customer`

- Last shopped (redundant)
- Usually shops (redundant)
- First shopped (redundant)
- Registered (perhaps not redundant)

Comment: Thanks Graphain.  I can see that it's all in the context!